# Regarding RSU address in message

Tags: veins

I added the following lines in `onData` method of my *TracIDemoRSU11p.cc* file:

```
void TraCIDemoRSU11p::onData(WaveShortMessage* wsm) {
    findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,green");

    annotations->scheduleErase(1, annotations->drawLine(wsm->getSenderPos(), mobi->getCurrentPosition(), "blue"));
    static int count=0;
    count++;
    if(count>100)
    {
        wsm->setCount(count);
        sendMessage(wsm->getWsmData());
    }
}
```

What I want is to get the vehicle's address which has sent the data as well.
Also, is there any problem in using the static variables in the method?

I have defined a count variable in wsm message and I want to send the count value along with the vehicleId in the message.

Answer (score 0):

Amending the message definition to include a vehicle id is allowed. So is using static variables in C++. I don't think it is a good idea though.

The static variable will be shared among all instances of that class (that is, across nodes and - possibly - simulation runs). I would recommend using a regular member variable of some class.

Comment: Can you please suggest an alternative to static variable.I want to update the count whenever I receive a message from the vehicle and send the value of count back to the vehicle??

Comment: I amended the answer